# Python change machine. Issues with calculating correct values

Tags: python

I dont really know what is wrong with my code. I've been working on it for a couple of days, and have posted mulitple times on this forum, but to no avail. This is the output i receive:
[image]

The results for stock should be 8 q, 10 d, 9 n, 8 p
Also the final stock in a previous iteration needs to be the starting stock for the next iteration and so on. That is why I have the while loop. At this point if you can correct my code and post it that would be fine, I don't really care (if you really want to, even though I dont expect anyone will). Hints are great! I honestly think that the issue is syntactical or in the while loop. Any help would be beneficial!
P.s. I have to use loops, functions aren't allowed

```
pennies = 10
nickels = 10
dimes = 10
quarters = 10

quarters_spent = 0
dimes_spent = 0
nickels_spent = 0
pennies_spent = 0

print("\nWelcome to change-making program.")
in_str = input("\nEnter the purchase price (xx.xx) or `q' to quit: ")

while in_str.lower() != 'q':
    dollar_str, cents_str = in_str.split(".")

    if in_str.lower() == 'q':
        quit()

    in_int = int(float(in_str) * 100)

    if in_int < 0:
        print("Error: purchase price must be non-negative.")
        in_str = input("\nEnter the purchase price (xx.xx) or `q' to quit: ")

    if in_int > 0:
        payment = input("\nInput dollars paid: ")
        payment_int = int(float(payment) * 100)
        change = payment_int - in_int

        #determines if there payment input
        if payment_int < in_int:
            print("Error: Insufficient payment.")
            payment = input("\nInput dollars paid: ")
            payment_int = int(float(payment) * 100)
            change = payment_int - in_int


        if change == 0:
            print("No change.")

        #determines how many quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies are left
        while change >= 25 and quarters > 0:
            change = change - 25
            quarters_spent += 1
            quarters = quarters - quarters_spent

        while change >= 10 and dimes > 0:
            change = change - 10
            dimes_spent += 1
            dimes = dimes - dimes_spent

        while change >= 5 and nickels > 0:
            change = change - 5
            nickels_spent += 1
            nickels = nickels - nickels_spent

        while change >= 1 and pennies > 0:
            change = change - 1
            pennies_spent += 1
            pennies = pennies - pennies_spent



        if quarters == 0 and dimes == 0 and nickels == 0 and pennies == 0:
            print("Error: ran out of coins.")
            quit()

        print("\nCollect Payment Below:")
        if quarters_spent > 0:
            print(quarters_spent, "Quarters")
        if dimes_spent > 0:
            print(dimes_spent, "Dimes")
        if nickels_spent > 0:
            print(nickels_spent, "Nickels")
        if pennies_spent > 0:
            print(pennies_spent, "Pennies")

        print("\nStock: ", quarters, "Quarters, ", dimes, " Dimes, ", nickels, " Nickels, ", pennies, " Pennies ")

        in_str = input("\nEnter the purchase price (xx.xx) or `q' to quit: ")

        pennies = pennies
        nickels = nickels
        dimes = dimes
        quarters = quarters
```

Comment: Why do you have `if in_str.lower() == 'q':`? You already test that in the `while` condition, it can't be true inside the loop.

Comment: You never use `dollar_str` or `cents_str`.

Comment: Alright. Ill pop it outside

Comment: What's the point of the statements like `pennies = pennies` at the bottom of the loop?

Comment: I did that to update the value after each iteration

Comment: You're not updating anything, you're setting variables to themselves.

Comment: Alright. I deleted them, but still having a problem. Also thanks for trying to help me out as well

Comment: You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is lines like this one:

```
quarters = quarters - quarters_spent
```

Each time through the loop, you're adding 1 to `quarters_spent`. So the first time you subtract `1` from `quarters`, the next time you subtract `2` from `quarters`, and so on. You should just subtract `1` from quarters each time.

```
    while change >= 25 and quarters > 0:
        change -= 25
        quarters_spent += 1
        quarters -= 1
```

and similarly for the other coins.

Also, if each purchase is just supposed to show the change for that purchase, not the accumulated change from all purchases, you should set `quarters_spent`, `dimes_spent`, `nickels_spent`, and `pennies_spent` to `0` inside the loop, before calculating the change.